# Kile - syntax highlighting of new command

Tags: highlighting, syntax, kile

I made the following changes to my `/usr/share/kde4/apps/katepart/syntax/latex.xml` file for Kile:

1. in the `<highlighting><contexts>` section, I added the line

   ```
   <StringDetect String="\lm{" attribute="Math" context="MathModeEnsure" />
   ```
2. next, i added the following block:

   ```
   <!-- math mode: \lm{...} !-->
   <context name="MathModeEnsure" attribute="Math" lineEndContext="#stay">
       <DetectChar char="{" attribute="Math" context="MathModeEnsure" />
       <DetectChar char="}" attribute="Math" context="#pop" />
       <IncludeRules context="MathModeCommon" />
   </context>
   ```

As expected, when i write `\lm{p\to q}` (for example) the code appears all in green. However, I'd like to have only what is inside the brackets highlighted in this manner, and the `\lm{}` command highlighted as `\emph{}`, say.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I assume from your first line that you're using Kile, but you should really specify it. As I understand it this is solely about syntax highlighting in your editor, and then *which* editor you're using is quite essential information.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Kile, sorry not to mention it.